# sizeForItemAtIndexPath not work with custom flowLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've replaced default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with my custom **subclass** of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and I found that `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` didn't work any longer.
Did I miss something, or I should set **itemSize** in my custom flowLayout?

Comment: Please add a code of your custom layout class. Usually it means that you are not calling some super implementations of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout `, or returning wrong collection view size.

Comment: I have override those methods: `prepareLayout` `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`
`layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`
`layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind`
`initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElementOfKind`.

And I didn't call `[super XXXX]` in any of those, also I didn't set itemSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subclass, use `itemSize` instead:

```
- (CGSize)itemSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(100,100);
}
```

Comment: Yap, it works. So it means that when using custom flowlayout `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will be ignored???

weired

Comment: I don't know but I found that event will not fire, use `customFlowLayout` and `itemSize` is good for now.